# Highcharts width exceeds container div on first load

Tags: jquery-mobile, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts with jQuery Mobile.

I have an area graph being drawn within a jQM `data-role="content"` container and within that container I have the following divs:

```html
<div style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; position: relative; width: 100%;">
    <div id="hg_graph" style="width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

My highcharts graph is a basic graph taken from one of their examples where I have not set the chart `width` property.

On the first load the graph exceeds the width of the containing divs, but when I resize the browser it snaps to the appropriate width.

How can I make it so that the width of it is right on first page load and not just on resize?

I've reviewed similar posts on stack overflow and none of the solutions seem to work.

**UPDATES**

1. I've identified the problem is that the dynamically generated `<rect>` tag by Highcharts is taking the full width of the browser window on page load and not taking it from the containiner div width at all.  Here's the html generated when I inspect:

   `<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" **width="1920"** height="200"></rect>`
2. I tried to reproduce in JSFiddle, but it seems to work fine there, which really has me stumped. Here's my JSFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/meandnotyou/rMXnY

Comment: So prolebm is resolved, am I right ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan No. It's not resolved. The most upvoted answer just cuts off the graph!

Comment: Still not yet resolved. Is this problem already post as issue in its GitHub Repository?

Comment: I'm stuck with this sh** too ! :(

Answer (score 45):

To call `chart.reflow()` helped me. 
Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

Comment: This is the best answer. This is the correct way. This is the only thing that worked for me. Thannnnnks!!!!! Solved hours of frustration

Comment: I feel sorry for people who don't see this answer. UPVOTE THIS ANSWER!

Comment: How do you call chart.reflow()? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. I see the chart property but cannot find a method to call.

Comment: Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/reflow-false/

this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.opts);
this.chart.reflow();

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work atleast in my case where 3 charts are placed side by side, however, the solution above works where width and height are set to 100%

Comment: For a CSS only workaround that might help see my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67324020/2108257

Answer (score 34):

this works like magic

put in your css file following

```
.highcharts-container {
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This hides part of the graph

Comment: Do you have any idea how long I spent on trying to get this to work for me. And it's as simple as this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know why this works though? And why isn't it fixed in Highcharts?

Comment: For me it worked using adding to highcharts-container position: absolute and the parent container position: relative together with this response.

Comment: This doesn't make the chart fit, it simply forces it's container to not break out of *it's* parent container. This makes the chart extend past `highcharts-container`, which no longer shows a scrollbar. This is by no means a solution to the root problem.

Comment: Its working width but data is not showing if i moved window screen data is coming first time data is now visable

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA this doesn't make chart extend past container, infact chart fits inside container as the width and height of class "highcharts-container" are adjusted to parent by the code

Comment: @comeOnGetIt I posted that comment after I tried your proposed solution, but I couldn't get it to work... it was a while back and I don't remember exact details, but looking back now, I *suspect* I may have had some other CSS rules affecting my test page.. just tried to remove my down-vote, but I can't unless the answer is edited, so if you do that please let me know.

Comment: In vue:
`<highcharts :options="chartOptions" class="highchart-container"></highcharts>
<style scoped>.highchart-container {  width: 100% important;  height: 100% !important;}
</style>`

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem, in my case had a graph of highchart that  it is shown  after click a button. I put `$(window).resize();` after show event and it solved the problem correctly. I hope you serve.

Comment: I used the same, seems the most elegant solution on this page.

Comment: For anyone having sizing issued because their Highchart starts out in a container that isn't displayed when the page loads, this approach will give you the most consistent results.

Comment: This is what I was doing, worked great until upgrading to version 6 :(

Answer (score 6):

Set width of the chart. That's the only option that worked for me.

```
chart: {
            type: 'line',
            width: 835
        },
```

Comment: Its worked only dynamically in large screens if we use responsive .?

Answer (score 4):

Define the highcharts inside the document ready:

```
<div style="width:50%" id="charts">
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#chart).highcharts(){
    ...
    });
)};
```

Hope it works ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with centering the highcharts graph it gave. It would center and size correctly for some resolutions but not all. When it didn't, I had the exact same symptoms you're describing here.

I fixed it by attaching/overriding additional css to the highcharts default.

so in a custom css file, adding

```
.highcharts-container{
/** Rules it should follow **/
}
```

should fix your issue. Assuming that your div "hg=graph" has nothing but highcharts.

Comment: I've tried overriding the div that's holding the highchart graph with various properties, but can't seem to get it right.  Can you post an example of the CSS rules you used?  Also, I've updated my post with more info.

Comment: The one I used was {margin: 0 auto;} Since I wanted to center mine. There is a chance that the class you need to override isn't the one I mentioned. If you view source on your page, inspect your hg_graph div and find the underlying container that highcharts use.

Comment: Hi Tim.. I found the class and it is .highcharts-container.  I've tried specifying `width: 100% !important` or editing inline in Chrome's DevTools, which does successfully restricts the container to the proper width now, but the graph is still 1920px wide and overflows, but hidden beyond the container.  The problem seems to be that on first load the `<SVG>` element generated by Highcarts has a defined width in pixels, so changing the container doesn't really do anything as the graph will just overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't help you more, as I was simply building it for PC and not mobile. The other thing is that I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish overall. Are you trying to limit the size of the graph by scale? Because 100% of a screen will be the entire screen, and 100% of that 100% is still that entire screen... So that might be your overflow?

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I'm testing on Chrome on my PC right now, so it has nothing to do with mobile or not.  Basically I have a parent container that has padding: 1%.  In that container is the hg_graph div that has a width of 100%.  So basically, it's width should be 98% of the total screen size.  When HighCharts generates the graph, it's getting the full page width and not the width of hg_graph (98%).  This only occurs on first page load.  If I resize the browser Highcharts automatically re-renders itself into the proper width of 98%.

Answer (score 3):

For those using angular and custom-built components, remember to define a dimensioned `display` in css (such as `block` or `flex`) for the host element.

And when the chart container has padding, you might find this indispensable:

**html**

```
<chart (load)="saveInstance($event.context)">
...
</chart>
```

**ts**

```
  saveInstance(chartInstance: any) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chart.reflow();
    }, 0);
  }
```

Otherwise the chart will bleed past the container on load and get its correct width only at next browser reflow (eg. when you start to resize window).

Comment: Hello
I tried this but it gives me following error: [ts] Property 'reflow' does not exist on type 'Chart'.

Comment: Haven't followed Highcharts recently, might be that the API changed, cannot really help now, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to call chart.reflow in render event function [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render);

```
 Highcharts.stockChart( 'chartContainer', {
 chart: {
  events: {
    render: function() {
      this.reflow();
    }
  },
  zoomType: 'x',
   ...
},
```

and remember to set min-width to zero and overflow to hidden in chart container.

```
#chartContainter {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem today - not on mobile, but with a window sized small on first page load.  When the page loads, the chart is hidden, then after some selections on the page, we create the chart.  We have set a min-width and max-width for the container in css, but not a width.

When the chart is being created, it needs to determine the dimensions to create the SVG .  **Since the chart is hidden, it cant get the dimensions properly so the code clones the chart container, positions it off-screen and appends it to the body so that it can determine the height/width.**

Since the width is not set, the cloned div tries to take as much space as it can - up to the max-width that I had set.  The SVG elements are created using that width, but added to the chart container div which currently is smaller (based on the size of the screen).  The result is that the chart extends past the container div's boundaries.

After the chart has rendered the first time, the on-screen dimensions are known and the clone function is not called.  This means that any window resizes, or reloading of the chart data cause the chart to size correctly.

I got around this initial-load problem by overriding the Highcharts function `cloneRenderTo` which clones the div to get dimensions:

```
(function (H) {
    // encapsulated variables
    var ABSOLUTE = 'absolute';

    /**
    * override cloneRenderTo to get the first chart display to fit in a smaller container based on the viewport size
    */
    H.Chart.prototype.cloneRenderTo = function (revert) {
        var clone = this.renderToClone,
            container = this.container;

        // Destroy the clone and bring the container back to the real renderTo div
        if (revert) {
            if (clone) {
                this.renderTo.appendChild(container);
                H.discardElement(clone);
                delete this.renderToClone;
            }

            // Set up the clone
        } else {
            if (container && container.parentNode === this.renderTo) {
                this.renderTo.removeChild(container); // do not clone this
            }
            this.renderToClone = clone = this.renderTo.cloneNode(0);
            H.css(clone, {
                position: ABSOLUTE,
                top: '-9999px',
                display: 'block' // #833
            });
            if (clone.style.setProperty) { // #2631
                clone.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
            }
            doc.body.appendChild(clone);

            //SA: constrain cloned element to width of parent element
            if (clone.clientWidth > this.renderTo.parentElement.clientWidth){
                clone.style.width = '' + this.renderTo.parentElement.clientWidth + 'px';
            }

            if (container) {
                clone.appendChild(container);
            }
        }
    }

})(Highcharts);
```

I saved this function in a separate script file that loads after the Highchart.js script has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try and encapsulate the highchart generation inside a pageshow event

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#hg_graph", function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem (for my case) by ensuring that the containing UI elements render *before* the chart, allowing Highcharts to calculate the correct width.

For example:

Before:

```
var renderChart = function(){
...
};
renderChart();
```

After:

```
var renderChart = function(){
...
};
setTimeout(renderChart, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue too, and the .highcharts-container css solution wasn't working for me. I managed to solve it for my case by splitting out an ng-class condition (which was setting different widths for the container div) into separate divs.

eg, this

```
<div ng-class="condition?'col-12':'col-6'">
    <chart></chart>
</div>
```

into

```
<div ng-show="condition" class="col-12">
    <chart></chart>
</div>
<div ng-show="!condition" class="col-6">
    <chart></chart>
</div>
```

I couldn't really tell you why it worked though. I'm guessing the ng-class takes longer to calculate the container width and so highcharts renders first with an undefined width? Hopefully this helps someone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue in my app where i am using angular
and i also using ngCloak directive which i have removed as i don't need it

after doing this my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen that sometimes there are several issues going on at the same time.

**If it happens the height exceed the expected heigh:**

SCSS style:

```
.parent_container{

    position:relative;

    .highcharts-container{position: absolute; width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
}
```

If the **width exceeds the container (bigger than what's supposed to) or does not resize properly to smaller one**:

```
    let element = $("#"+id);
    element.highcharts({...});

    // For some reason it exceeds the div height.
    // Trick done to reflow the graph. 
    setTimeout(()=>{
        element.highcharts().reflow();
    }, 100 );
```

The last one happened to me when destroying the chart and creating a new one... the new one was coming with width extra size.

Answer (score 0):

I have been also bump into this issue. both affected in desktop and mobile view of the chart.

In my case i have a **Chart that update the series color depending on min or max**.After updating the points, the highcharts width exceeds container div on its first load.

To fix that, what i did is add ***chart.reflow();*** after the update of points.

**CODE:**

```
//First declare the chart
var chart = $('#TopPlayer').highcharts();
//Set the min and max
var min = chart.series[0].dataMin; //Top Losser
var max = chart.series[0].dataMax; //Top Winner

for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].points.length; i++) {
    if (chart.series[0].points[i].y === max) {
        chart.series[0].points[i].update({
            color: 'GREEN',
        });
    }
    if (chart.series[0].points[i].y === min) {
        chart.series[0].points[i].update({
            color: 'RED',
        });
    }
}

// redraw the chart after updating the points
chart.reflow();
```

Hope this helps to those who has the same issue like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me ! The charts were working fine for a while and then after a feature they started exceeding their container. Turns out it was the defer attribute on the script in the head of my application.

Try removing defer on your javascript tags:

`<script defer src="script.js"></script>`
to
`<script src="script.js"></script>`

Or moving my stylesheet link higher in the head also seemed to fix it but it's a less reliable solution..

Answer (score 0):

This may have been introduced since the OP in 2013, but you should be able to set height with `chart.height` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height)

```
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        height: window.innerHeight + 'px',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Top 10 Users',
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'by scores',
                    },
```

This is a web based solution, but I would expect you could cater it to jQuery.mobile

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me. I dynamically change chart data and the top answer solution ruins the animations and causes a jump in the chart position.

The workaround that I finally came up with was to set some padding for the chart wrapper element (in my case some part of the chart to left was hidden, so I gave some left padding), and then set the chart main element overflow property to visible. It works and the animations are just fine. You may need some experimenting with padding value to get it perfectly displayed.

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
   <!-- high charts main element here -->
</div>
```

and the style

```
.chart-wrapper{
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.chart-wrapper > div:first-child{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

reflow() on load event solve my issue

```
chart: {
    height,
    events: {
      load: function () {
        this.reflow();
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35513129)

Answer (score -1):

for me, I set chart width:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        **width:3000**,
        ..... }
```

and in html set `overflow:auto`

```
<div id="container" style="**width:100%;overflow:auto**;" ></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this for way too long, and found a solution that works for me.  A little bit of background on my setup:

1. The highcharts chart was loading on a tab on my website that is not visible upon logging into the site.
2. When switching to that tab, the chart was well outside the div.

So, I attached a unique ID to that particular tab, we'll call it `tab5`, and then bound a click function that forced - and this is the important part - the **`<svg>`** element within the container div to 100% using jQuery:

```
$('#tab5').bind('click', function() {
    $('#container_div svg').width('100%');
});
```

...and my sanity has been restored.  For the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Please add `width:100%` to chart container.
Hope this will resolve `overflow:hidden` related issue.

```
classname{min-height:450px;width: 100%;}
```