# highchart's hidden chart renders out of container in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm trying to create a full responsive highchart's pie chart in angular that is inside a div that is hidden with `ng-show`.

I've read similar questions about how to use jquery to fix this issue: ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436666/highcharts-issue-about-full-chart-width), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240254/highcharts-width-exceeds-container-div-on-first-load), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240254/highcharts-width-exceeds-container-div-on-first-load))

I have tried:

1. `$(window).resize()` but it didn't work
2. `$scope.$apply()` worked, but it's keeps throwing an already digest cycle error
3. I can specify the width using the high chart's property `width : "string"`, but the chart will not be responsive and stay with the same width all the time.

#### [Here is a Plunker of the error](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fnEnFNKsqnkm7OHsZqy)

> **Note**: Just make the view window large enough, so that when you press the button you can see, that the chart is on top of the div.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use one of the angular wrappers for highstocks like https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng or create a directive like below to serve the purpose

```
<div high-chart id="chart" chartData="chart" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px">
</div>
```

Bind the data to the 'chart' in the controller and create the directive ,

```
.directive('highChart',function(){

      return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
          chart:'=chartdata'
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
          scope.$watch('chart',function(newV){
            if(newV){
            $('#chart').highcharts('StockChart', {
                rangeSelector : {
                    inputEnabled: $('#chart').width() > 480,
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
                },

                series : [{
                    type : 'scatter',
                    name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                    data : newV,
                    dataGrouping : {
                        units : [
                            [
                                'week', // unit name
                                [1] // allowed multiples
                            ], [
                                'month',
                                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            });
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
```

Hope that helps .

Comment: thanks for the answer, i would try this and tell you if it works

Comment: hi @32teeths i tried with highcharts-ng but it isn't resposnive, he use the approach of the fixed width, and i couldn't find a example on the internet of his directive with a responsive behavior, thanks for the help