# ng2-highcharts : how to trigger reflow event?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using ng2-highcharts and I am developing in IntelliJ and searching in my intellisense, I can't seem to find the correct object to manually trigger a reflow event for certain situations? How can I do this?

My need for reflow access in ng2-highcharts pertains to this documented issue in highcharts [Highcharts width exceeds container div on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240254/highcharts-width-exceeds-container-div-on-first-load), as well as some other cases where I am not triggering a window resize event when things are changing width on my screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Highcharts does not have a reflow event. It is a [chart's method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.reflow) which can be called after resizing window/container/etc. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-reflow/. If you want to listen when the chart resizes you can use redraw event  - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I knew this much, but calling it from ng2-highcharts is my question.